# Should I remove old items from state during infinite scroll for performance reasons?

Tags: reactjs, performance, pagination, infinite-scroll, state-management

I'm currently developing a React application that features an infinite scroll list. This list displays data fetched from a server, which holds a large amount of items (approx. 16,000). I fetch and display the data 10 items at a time using pagination on the server-side.

To mitigate performance issues associated with storing a large number of items in the state, I'm considering removing older items (i.e., items from previous pages) from the state once the user has scrolled past a certain point and loaded enough new pages.

I'm concerned about how this would affect the user experience. If a user scrolls up, they would see a loading spinner while I re fetch and display the previous page's items. This goes against the principle of an infinite scroll, where the expectation is to smoothly scroll through all items without seeing loading spinners in the middle of the list.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to remove older items from state in an infinite scroll list for performance reasons?
2. Is there a better approach to handle this scenario in order to maintain a smooth user experience and also mitigate potential performance issues due to a large state?
3. How do big tech companies (e.g., Facebook, Instagram) handle similar scenarios in their infinite scroll lists?